# WMI error on FDCC/USGCB domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, wmi

Our lab recent moved to a domain with FDCC/USGCB policies and we ran into a number of problems with our client / server configuration.  Rather than outline everything, I point you to a link and simply say that the Windows Management Interface (WMI) was the failing point.

From the researcher's client PC (Windows XP Pro) to the lab's server (Windows Server 2003) we found that two easily simulated errors were produce by our previously functioning .NET applications.  Power Shell can be used to duplicate the error without having to go into all the .NET WMI code.

PS > Get-Wmiobject Win32_GroupUser -Computer {server} -Credential {domain\server} ...

The first error, "Security Package Specific" error "80070721" turned out to be caused by a duplicate entry for the same server on both the old Domain and the new FDCC/USGCB domain.

The second error,  "RPC Server is Unavailable" with the code "800706BA" has not yet been resolved.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

More details at: https://sites.google.com/site/eibflowlab/wmi-work

dgp

Comment: the rpc error is going to a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prove whether WMI is working do the following.

1. execute wmi query at the server. Something like "wmic os get name" will suffice.
2. Take a Netmon/Wireshark network trace and do the same query remotely against server from the PC to make sure query is going to correct server. "wmic /node: os get name"

I am not sure if you have a firewall related issue here. I am not familiar with the FDCC/USGCB policies and whether they are blocking WMI queries. Although I'd recommend getting a RSOP report of resulting policies using "gpresult /h rsopreport.htm" and checking for any windows firewall related hints.

Comment: Two great suggestions, thanks.  As commented on by tony roth, it turned out that when we removed the anti-virus we were able to get past the RPC error.  We then installed ESET anti-virus like the rest of the PCs on the new domain and all was well.  The idea to create the RSoP report is going to provide us with a nice baseline down the road.  I'm not fully conversant in the USGCB specs, so the report is a good starting point.